# Reclassification of raster by classification method in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, spatial-analyst, qgis-processing, reclassify

I am trying to reclass my raster data based on the reclassification methods ( equal interval, quantile,..) in QGIS like we do in ArcMap. I don't see any tool in QGIS to perform reclassification of raster by classification method.

Comment: Did you try `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Reclassify by layer (or table)`?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there's no straightforward quantile/interval reclassification (except for display but w/o modifying the raster values).

While there *might* be a [suitable plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/) for convenience, a full QGIS install [borrows](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html) a lot of functionalities from [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/) and [SAGA](https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/en/index.html).
In the case of GRASS, you should be able to access these in the Processing Toolbox (CTRL+ALT+T). Browse the tool explorer for GRASS > raster > [r.reclass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.reclass.html)).

Or, if you're more into scripting, you can use the [Python console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229796/reclassify-a-raster-file-with-quantiles).